# Is there a combination of sapply and lapply that circumvents calling both function?

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I apologize in advance if my title is not the best way to frame the topic of my question...

Currently I use a combination of `sapply` and `lapply` to preallocate two lists, `Ag1` and `Al1`, setting upper and lower bounds on their entries based on a vector of integers `A` and an integer `B`.  Here goes:

```
A = c(7,5,3,4,2)
B = 4
Ag1 = sapply(lapply(B - A, function(a) a), function(b) max(1,b))
Al1 = sapply(lapply(B + A, function(a) a), function(b) min(1,b))
```

Can I accomplish this more efficiently without using the combination of `sapply` and `lapply`?

Comment: `pmax(B-A, 1); pmin(B+A, 1)`

Comment: good point on the use of pmin and pmax

Comment: There’s the fundamental question why you think `lapply(B - A, function(a) a)` is necessary at all …

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem you're actually trying to solve more complicated? Your example can be simplified by simply combining the functions.

```
A = c(7,5,3,4,2)
B = 4
Ag1 = sapply(B - A, function(a) max(1, a))
Al1 = sapply(B + A, function(a) min(1, a))

> Ag1
[1] 1 1 1 1 2

> Al1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: this works well, thanks.  The `pmin` and `pmax` solutions from @d.b are nice.  These functions are part of a bigger process.  The size of `A` will vary but the size of `B` will stay the same.  Cheers